# How to change case only of current letter with RE?

Tags: java, regex

I need to change case of first letter of every word

```
 String regex = "\\b\\w";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
        while(m.find()){    
            input = input.replaceAll("\\b"+m.group(),switchCase(m.group()));
        }
```

if words have same first case, it will change previous as well

example

`Input: hello all Hello`

`My Output: hello All hello`

`Correct output: Hello All hello`

how i can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Java 11+**, I would do it like this, to get *full Unicode support*:

```java
public static String switchCase(String input) {
    return Pattern.compile("\\b\\p{L}").matcher(input)
                  .replaceAll(mr -> switchCase(mr.group().codePointAt(0)));
}

private static String switchCase(int codePoint) {
    return Character.toString(Character.isLowerCase(codePoint)
                              ? Character.toTitleCase(codePoint)
                              : Character.toLowerCase(codePoint));
}
```

*Test*

```java
System.out.println(switchCase("hello all Hello"));
```

*Output*

```
Hello All hello
```

---

Since [`Character.toString​(int codePoint)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html) wasn't added until **Java 11**, the *second method* needs to be changed for **Java 1.5 to Java 10**:

```java
private static String switchCase(int codePoint) {
    return new String(new int[] { Character.isLowerCase(codePoint)
                                  ? Character.toTitleCase(codePoint)
                                  : Character.toLowerCase(codePoint) }, 0, 1);
}
```

---

Since [`replaceAll​(Function<MatchResult,​String> replacer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.Function)) wasn't added until **Java 9**, the *first method* needs to be changed for **Java 1.5 to Java 8**:

```java
public static String switchCase(String input) {
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\b\\p{L}").matcher(input);
    while (m.find())
        m.appendReplacement(buf, switchCase(m.group().codePointAt(0)));
    return m.appendTail(buf).toString();
}
```